# Windows 10: Mic Failure

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

My laptop is running on **Windows 10 version 1903**. I installed this version last week and I am sure this issue comes after 1903 is installed, previously version 1803 & 1809 I have no such problem at all. It stays undetected until today I was trying to communicate with my gaming friends on Discord and found out my mic isn't working properly. After further investigation I realize something is wrong with the system configuration (software issue), the mic issue is not solely on Discord. I googled for almost an hour, literally went through 10+ articles (90% of their methods are similar) and tried out every single possible fix. Finally ended up none of them works. Someone please save me, I am so lost right now.

### What I have tried:

- Make sure the earphone I am using is functional, both I/O.
- Make sure my laptop's audio port is functional.
- Make sure my single-jack earphone cable is properly plugged in the single earphone port. No splitter & converter used.
- *Settings > Privacy > App permissions (Microphone)*, make sure "Allow apps to access your microphone" is on.
- *Device Manager > Audio inputs and outputs*, both *Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio (SST))* and *Speakers (Realtek High Definiton Audio (SST))* make sure they are neither disabled, malfunction nor outdated.
- *Device Manager > Sound, video and game controllers*, both *Intel(R) Display Audio* and *Realtek High Definition Audio (SST)* make sure they are neither disabled, malfunction nor outdated.
- Uninstall and reinstall specified drivers above.
- *Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Communications tab*, check "Do nothing" for "When Windows detects communications activity:".
- *Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound > Recording tab > Microphone Array properties > Levels tab*, make sure my default mic is not muted, and volume set to max. In *Advanced tab*, disabled "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" to prevent intrusive app to take control over system settings. In *Enhancements tab*, tick  "Disable all sound effect" instead of "Immediate mode". In addition to this, make sure *Microphone Array* is set as default.
- Run Troubleshooter for Sound to check both drivers (Microphone Array & Speakers), no issue detected.
- Restart Windows Audio in Services.
- Run SRC Scan. Not sure if this action is relevant however, it resulted in some files are corrupted and unable to fix. I briefly went through the log file and it is likely referring to recent Windows Defender Definition Update. I personally think this has nothing to do with my mic issue here.
- Tried with every single option (Mic in, Speaker out, Headphone, Headset etc) when earphone is plugged in and a small window pops up. Headphone is chosen by default, and works properly under normal circumstances but not this time.
- Make sure no pending system update, checked for 10x times.
- Refer to official Microsoft support article in accordance with sound problem: [Fix sound problems in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/4026994/windows-10-fix-sound-problems). Nothing useful.
- Clean restart after every single action above taken.

I keep testing the mic in this window after every method tested and none of the fix above helps, the bar doesn't responding in green as supposed. I have **LITERALLY** no idea what is bugging the mic from working properly. This issue is way harder to fix than no sound issue, which previously fixed by myself for a few times.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a
[report](https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/135557-latest-realtek-audio-drivers-cause-mic-not-work.html)
claiming that the latest driver from Realtek that Windows installs (5/22/19 release)
is problematic. It was claimed that the audio driver released in January 2019
is the one that works.

Try this :

- In Device Manager enter the Properties of your Microphone (which is what device?)
- In Details tab, note and report here the value of the property "Driver version"
- In Driver tab, click Roll Back Driver if enabled and test
- If disabled or the above did not help, uninstall the audio device
  together with its driver, unplug mic, and reboot the computer.

Comment: I believe the _Mircrophone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio (SST))_ is the in-charge mic driver. Its version is 10.0.18362.1 (Date 18/3/19). Roll Back Driver is unavailable. Reinstall is not helpful.

Comment: My driver is same version and works. You are sure you are looking at the right mic device?